# Why this error trying to split the routes related to a specific module in my Angular application?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-module, angular13

I am finding this problem following an Angular course. Basically the instructor it is showing how to split the routing from the **app.module.ts** file putting the route related to a specific module into the related module.

Basically I have an **AuthModule** that is related the authentication component of my app and the instructor is showing as to shift the authentication routes into this module. So this is my situation:

This is my **AppModule** class realted the main module of my application:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WelcomeComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    SidenavListComponent,
    StopTrainingComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    TrainingModule,
    AuthModule
  ],
  providers: [AuthService,
              TrainingService,
              UIService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  
})
export class AppModule { }
```

As you can see here I am importing my **AuthModule** module class that is this one:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        SignupComponent,
        LoginComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        AngularFireAuthModule,
        SharedModule,
        AuthRoutingModule
    ],
    exports: []

})
export class AuthModule {

    
}
```

And as you can see this is importing this new module **AuthRoutingModule** containing the routing settings forn this authentication module, this one:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Route, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
import { SignupComponent } from "./signup/signup.component";

const routes: Route[
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AuthRoutingModule {

}
```

But doing in this way I am obtaining the following error when my application is compiled:

```
./src/app/auth/auth-routing.module.ts:4:12 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:12)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js
 * ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import * as i0 from "@angular/core";
| import * as i1 from "@angular/router";
> const routes, { path: , 'login': , component: LoginComponent };
| ;
| export class AuthRoutingModule {

Error: src/app/auth/auth-routing.module.ts:3:10 - error TS2440: Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'LoginComponent'.

3 import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/auth/auth-routing.module.ts:7:3 - error TS2538: Type '{ path: "signup"; component: SignupComponent; }' cannot be used as an index type.

7   { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/auth/auth-routing.module.ts:7:49 - error TS1005: ']' expected.

7   { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
                                                  ~


Error: src/app/auth/auth-routing.module.ts:8:10 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable '(Missing)'.

8   { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
           


Error: src/app/auth/auth-routing.module.ts:8:11 - error TS1003: Identifier expected.

8   { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
            ~~~~~~~


Error: src/app/auth/auth-routing.module.ts:8:18 - error TS1005: ':' expected.

8   { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
                   ~


Error: src/app/auth/auth-routing.module.ts:8:18 - error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable '(Missing)'.

8   { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
                   


Error: src/app/auth/auth-routing.module.ts:9:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

9 ];
  ~




** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


✖ Failed to compile.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed an `=` that might be the issue.

```
const routes: Route = [
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
];
```

Answer (score 2):

you missed the equal operator around routes constant.